# QPainter not drawing consistently

Tags: c++, qt, qpainter

I'm programming a GUI that draws graphs with Qt. My painter is showing some inconsistency: It only paints the graph about 50% of the times that I run the exact same binary after compilation. I do call QPainter's begin(), and I also made sure that the parameters I'm passing to the drawing functions such as drawEllipse() are initialized and have valid values when I call the function.

Below is the relevant code (note that the parameter painter has been initialized and begin() has been called prior to this function):

```
void GraphWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) {
  QWidget::paintEvent(event);
  this->painter = new QPainter(this);
  painter->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
  // draw graph itself
  painter->translate(xOffset, yOffset);
  painter->scale(graphScale, graphScale);
  paintGraph(painter);
}

void GraphWidget::paintGraph() {
  if (this->graph) {
    // Iterate thought all edges and draw them
    for (Agnode_t *node = agfstnode(graph); node;
         node = agnxtnode(graph, node)) {
      for (Agedge_t *edge = agfstout(graph, node); edge;
           edge = agnxtout(graph, edge)) {
        drawEdge(edge);
      }
    }
    // Iterate through all nodes and draw them
    for (Agnode_t *node = agfstnode(graph); node;
         node = agnxtnode(graph, node)) {
      drawNode(node);
    }
  }
}

void GraphWidget::drawNode(Agnode_t *node) {

  ...

  //Height and width of node, in pixels.
  float scaleWidth = width * this->logicalDpiX();
  float scaleHeight = height * this->logicalDpiY();

  std::cout << "Drawing individual node. x = " << x << ". scaleWidth = " << scaleWidth << ". y = " << y << ". ScaleHeight = " << scaleHeight << "\n";
  //Actual node painting takes place here.
  painter->drawEllipse(x - scaleWidth / 2, y - scaleHeight / 2, scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

  ...

}

void GraphWidget::drawEdge(Agedge_t *edge) {
  // retrieve the position attribute and parse it
  float lastx, lasty, x, y;
  getNodePos(agtail(edge), lastx, lasty);
  auto spline_list = ED_spl(edge)->list;
  for (int i = 0; i < spline_list->size; i++) {
    x = spline_list->list[i].x;
    y = spline_list->list[i].y;
    painter->drawLine(lastx, lasty, x, y);
    lastx = x;
    lasty = y;
  }
  getNodePos(aghead(edge), x, y);
  painter->drawLine(lastx, lasty, x, y);
}
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Unless there's an awful lot of code please show the full `GraphWidget::drawNode` and `GraphWidget::paintEvent` implementations -- or at least *all* relevant parts thereof.

Comment: Sorry - I just added all of the relevant painting functions ! Hope this helps more and thanks. I'm working with Graphviz, in case you're wondering about the Agnode_t, and Agedge_t objects. They're from the Graphviz library.

Comment: Not sure it's part of the problem but... you're leaking `QPainter`s left, right and centre.  Why allocate the `QPainter` on the heap at all.  Get rid of the `painter` member and just use `QPainter painter(this)`.  You can then also remove the calls to `QPainter::begin/end/save/restore`.

Comment: Thanks for the input - I fixed that and the behavior is still the same (although now the code is cleaner and better).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. Calling `painter->translate(xOffset, yOffset)` was causing the painter issues because when I first opened the window, `xOffset` and `yOffset` were uninitialized so my guess is they took random values and the graph was being translated to some random spot where I couldn't see it. I just made sure to initialize the offset variables to 0 in the constructor and this fixed the problem.